# Limit controls must follow a math operator

Tags: amsmath, babel, unicode

I'm receiving "Limit controls must follow a math operator" error. Googled it, tried, nothing helped. Appears on Overleaf 2.0, using makefile in Cent OS, Fedora. Using pkgs *geometry, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, verbatim, babel (czech), inputenc (utf8), fontenc (IL2)*

```
l.99 ...� $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ a $\Pi\limits _{i=1}^n 2^i$...
I'm ignoring this misplaced \limits or \nolimits command.
```

The line looks like this:

```
... ${\lim_{x\to\infty}f(n)}$ ... $\Pi_{i=1}^n 2^i$ ... $\bigcup_{A\in B}A$... $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ ... $\Pi\limits_{i=1}^n 2^i$ ... \verb|\limits|
```

---

EDIT1:
Found that problem starts at `${\Pi\limits_{i=1}^{n} 2^i}$`. Unfortunately, i need \limits for \sum and \Pi or anything, that forces the `\Pi` to have compact form (n above, i=1 under), it's school homework :)

Any advice appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\Pi` is a symbol not an operator, you are probably looking for `\prod` which is the product operator (which uses `\Pi` as its symbol but has a different category).

Comment: Haha, didn't expect it to be that. LaTeX :D thx